# Do you have to have thieves' tools in order to pick a lock?

Tags: dnd-5e, equipment

Does a character have to have thieves' tools (TT) in order to pick a lock? Not necessarily proficiency in the tool, but at least have the tool itself?

I'm confused about picking locks and whether or not it A) requires thieves tools to even attempt to open a lock (the description of the lock and manacles in the equipment section suggest they are), and B) if you need proficiency in TT to even use them (the "Working Together" section in PHB 175 suggestes you do). However the dexterity ability section on PHB 177 clearly lists "pick a lock" with no other qualifiers.

Clearly you can't pick a lock with just your fingers, so *some* type of tool is needed. I figure that improvising tools gives you disadvantage, while having the TT avoids that penalty. This allows my high dex characters to still attempt to open locks at any time (in a jail, stripped of their gear, etc) but obviously having the right equipment is a huge advantage.

So I ruled that picking a lock without TT is a dex roll with disadvantage, with TT (but not proficiency in them) is a normal DEX check, and proficiency lets you add your prof bonus to the roll (as the TT item entry seems to imply).

Answer (score 83, accepted):

## The Short Answer (TL;DR)

**You need Thieves' Tools to pick a lock *but* you don't need to be proficient with them.**

## The Long(er) Answer

**You (usually) need Thieves' Tools to pick a lock or disarm a trap *BUT* you (probably) don't need to be proficient with them (maybe).**

Exactly how you are meant to use Thieves' Tools isn't 100% explicitly and unequivocally covered by RAW (<del>yet</del> still) so this is *my* interpretation of those rules based on the rules I've found.

## Part 1: Do you need Thieves' Tools to pick a lock?

This part of the question is easy: **YES**

Thieves' Tools are (surprisingly) a tool:

> **Tools**
>
> A tool helps you do something *you couldn't otherwise do*, such as craft or repair an item, forge a document, or *pick a lock*.
>
> -PHB p.154/PBR p.50

This is pretty explicit and there aren't any contradictions to this general rule elsewhere. One potential problem is how to deal with *improvised* Thieves' Tools.  The DMG has given us some good basic rules to deal with improvised Thieves' Tools under the Sample Traps section:

> **Collapsing Roof**
>
> This trap uses a trip wire... A successful DC 15 Dexterity check using thieves' tools disables the trip wire harmlessly. A character without thieves' tools can attempt this check with disadvantage *using any edged weapon or edged tool*.  On a failed check, the trap triggers.
>
> -DMG p.122

It's probably allowable to use improvised Thieves' Tools (in most situations) providing you have something sensible to make them from (at your DM's discretion).  In addition, any lock picking or trap disarming check made with improvised Thieves' Tools should be made with **disadvantage** (if it's allowed at all).

## Part 2: Do you need to be proficient with Thieves' Tools to use them?

This is the trickier part of the question as there are a few contradictions and unclear rules for this in the PHB/DMG. An important thing to note though, is that there *isn't* a section in the PHB/DMG that handles lock picking *or* trap disarming specifically. This means that a lot of it comes down to you and your DM's interpretation of any **references** to using Thieves' Tools.

There are a good number of references to Thieves' Tools in the PHB and DMG so let's look at the relevant ones and see what they say:

### Equipment

The item descriptions for the Lock and Manacles both reference Thieves' Tools (though interestingly the Hunting *Trap* doesn't).

> **Lock.** [...] A key is provided with the lock. Without the key, *a creature proficient with thieves’ tools can pick this lock with a successful DC 15 Dexterity check*.
>
> -PHB p.152/PBR p.49

and

> **Manacles.** [...] Each set of manacles comes with one key. Without the key, *a creature proficient with thieves’ tools can pick the manacles’ lock with a successful DC 15 Dexterity check*.
>
> -PHB p.152/PBR p.50

Both of these listings could be interpreted to say you have to have proficiency to be able to pick the lock.  However, as Cthos pointed out, a (fairly strict) reading doesn't actually **exclude** anyone who isn't proficient from making the check.

This could mean that a creature without proficiency in Thieves' Tools faces a DC 15 Dex check, a DC 15 Dex check *with disadvantage*, or even just a higher DC Dex check instead.

### Tools

The general Tool rules and the Thieves' Tools description both point towards proficiency being non-mandatory:

> **Tools**
>
> [...] Proficiency with a tool allows you to add your proficiency bonus to any ability check you make using that tool.
>
> -PHB p.154/PBR p.50/DMG p.239
>   *Note: The DMG wording is infinitesimally different (and essentially identical) to the rules in the PHB/PBR*

Since the phrasing of this is non-exclusive, like the equipment listings, it implies that you *can* take a non-proficient check with any tool.

Effectively, adding a proficiency bonus to a check (or not) is meant to simulate the "real world" impact of being proficient (or not) with whatever is involved in the ability check you're making.

> **Thieves' Tools.** [...] Proficiency with these tools lets you add your proficiency bonus to any ability checks you make to disarm traps or open locks.
>
> -PHB p.154/PBR v2 p.51

This description gives **absolutely no indication** that you need to be proficient to use Thieves' Tools, which I think is one of the strongest indicators that proficiency isn't required.

This is (quite surprisingly) the *only* main point of reference across the rule books. In addition, it also indirectly implies you can make a non-proficient check to disarm traps or open locks without getting your proficiency bonus *and* without disadvantage.

### Ability Checks

> **Working Together**
>   Sometimes two or more characters team up to attempt a
>   task.
>   [...]
>   A character can only provide help if the task is one that he or she could attempt alone. For example, *trying to open a lock requires proficiency with thieves’ tools*, so a character who lacks that proficiency can’t help another character in that task.
>
> -PHB p.175/PBR v2 p.59

This is the *second* strongest case for proficient use only - after all, it is *explicitly* stated that you need proficiency to open a lock. This is the only reference to outright state this though and it does contradict the *implications* of all previous rules.

It could be that in this case "specific beats general" and Thieves' Tools *specifically* need proficiency whereas other tools *generally* don't.  However, this would make them the only tools to need proficiency.

I also think this could very well be errata, missed in the final edits, based purely on where it is (i.e. this isn't in the description for Thieves' Tools).

> **Other Dexterity Checks.** The DM might call for a Dexterity check when you try to accomplish tasks like the following:
>
> - Control a heavily laden cart on a steep descent
> - Steer a chariot around a tight turn
> - *Pick a lock*
> - *Disarm a trap*
> - etc...
>
> -PHB p.177/PBR p.60 (v3)

Again, this is a reference to taking a Dex check with no other qualifiers requiring proficiency (this was pointed out by Jason K in the question)

### Mapping a Dungeon

> **Locked Doors**
>
> Characters who don't have the key for a locked door can pick the lock with a successful Dexterity check *(doing so requires thieves' tools **and** proficiency in their use)*.
>
> -DMG p.103

Ok, *this* provides the strongest argument for needing proficiency to use Thieves' Tools (and it's a strong argument one at that). This quote is pretty unflinching in terms of RAW and could be a deal breaker. However, as Jason K has pointed out, it is in a section that isn't about tools so could potentially be errata (and it isn't backed up by any other statements in the DMG.

### Traps

> If the adventurers detect a trap before triggering it, they might be able to disarm it, either permanently or long enough to move past it. You might call for an Intelligence (Investigation) check for a character to deduce what needs to be done, *followed by a Dexterity check using thieves' tools* to perform the necessary sabotage.
>
> -DMG p.121

Here, again, is another reference to making a Dexterity check without explicitly requiring proficiency. This could have just been left out if it's already assumed you *do* require proficiency but that's not really stated as a normal assumption.

### Twitter

Finally, for completeness, here's the tweet and reply between WaxEagle and Mike Mearls (co-lead designer of D&D 5e).

***Important:* I have stolen this directly from WaxEagles's answer purely for completeness. The effort on WaxEagle's part should be acknowledged here and I take no credit for this quote.**

> [Conversation](https://twitter.com/mikemearls/status/533109977141874688)
>
> WaxEagle: Could I get some clarity on thieves tools and lockpicking. Do you need the tools? Do you need proficiency?
>
> Mike Mearls: anyone can use tools, prof bonus adds if proficient. No tools, DM can say no check or disadvantage.

Again, this is a pretty major point for allowing non-proficient lockpicking (or trap disarming) but I believe Mike has previously stated that Jeremy Crawford is the "rules guy" so it's not absolute (unfortunately).

## Conclusion

After reading into the PHB and DMG, finding these rulings and taking them all together, my final assessment is still the same: I'd suggest that we can (and should) make the assumption that characters can *attempt* to use any tool they want.

Ultimately there is nothing **physically preventing** any character from picking up any tool, weapon, musical instrument, or set of armour they aren't proficient with and then trying to use it.

That said, a non-proficient character doesn't get their proficiency bonus *and* may also take an additional penalty, or have disadvantage (see non-proficiency with armour), so they're definitely less likely to achieve the outcome they want if they do try something unfamiliar.

If you're going for a "Gritty Realism" theme (DMG p. 267) to your campaign, then yeah, you could (house)rule that you need to be proficient and no amount of Dexterity is going to help without some kind of training or practice.

And that does kind of hold up in real life - ever tried to pick a lock before?  However, I think a lot of people would agree that these guys, your characters, are heroes! I'd prefer to give them the benefit of the doubt, at least where RAW is concerned.

It would be great to see a **definitive** answer from the development team of 5e (Jeremy Crawford, Mike Mearls, & co.) but I'm not sure how likely that is. We shall see...

To restate my conclusion:

**You do need Thieves' Tools to pick a lock *but* you don't need to be proficient with them.**

## Epilogue: How this works in practice

If you're still here and agree with my assessment, all this effectively means there are really only four scenarios you would come across when picking a lock:

1. You have Thieves' Tools and are proficient with them. You can pick the lock and get to add your proficiency bonus to the (Dex) check.
2. You have Thieves' Tools but you aren't proficient with them. You can still pick the lock but you don't get to add your proficiency bonus (since it's a bonus you only get when you are proficient with something).
3. You don't have any Thieves' Tools but you improvise some (with your DM's approval). You can still pick the lock but it's probably with disadvantage. If you have proficiency with the tools, add your bonus. If not, good luck with your roll!
4. No Thieves' Tools and no improvised tools. Take a strength check to throw the closest party member through the door or crowbar the lock. Basically, look for another way to get past it because you can't pick it.

Comment: The general rules for tools don’t require proficiency to use a tool, but the specific rules for locks *do* explicitly require proficiency with thieves’ tools. See the basic rules p. 49, for example.

Comment: @BraddSzonye You're absolutely right; Jason K and WaxEagle also both pointed out a few additional points that imply or state this in the PHB. However, IMO this could be an error due to changes in rules as 5e was being developed. WaxEagle's answer has Mike Mearles stance on it (via Twitter) and personally I think it makes the most sense this way, especially based on other tool use. Until the DMG comes out though, we're relying on conflicting interpretations of the PHB/Basic rules. Ultimately, using a *consistent* houserule is probably more important at this stage.

Comment: Wow, a lot of research! Boogles my mind that something so critical to DnD, usually having SPECIFIC skills dealing with it, got so glossed over in the PHB (and DMG). Really need a few "examples of play" from the design team to clear these kinds of things up.

Comment: @JasonK Haha yeah I did go a bit overboard... Unfortunately it was all wasted as well! The DMG disagrees with me so, as much as I appreciate being the accepted answer, I'll actually be changing my answer later today when I can grab my DMG. It turns out you do normally need proficiency to use Thieves' Tools. Personally I would still advocate the points I've made in my conclusion - there really is nothing stopping someone "having a go". Though this would be a houserule and probably give disadvantage + no proficiency bonus. Mind waiting for my final edit lol?

Comment: @JasonK Also, I completely agree - it would be great to see these kind of specific but vague rules demo'd or shown working by the development team.

Comment: Does the DMG contradict you? p239 Prof:Tools doesn't, many trap descriptions say you need TT, but don't mention prof (and use disadv if you don't have TT). Oh, wait, p103 does say that for picking locks. Again, a single throwaway line in a section not even talking about tools!

Comment: @JasonK Finally managed to add yet more to my ridiculously long answer. I think the reference on p.103 is throwaway enough to be arguable. Hopefully that should cover every relevant reference to Thieves' Tools and give you a good basis for your own houserules/house decision. I have also just Tweeted Jason Crawford to see if he can clarify (as WaxEagle did with Mike Mearls). Should be interesting to see if they agree. I think I need to lie down now, the word "proficiency" doesn't look like a real word to me any more...

Comment: FYI, Mearls stated that Crawford was the "official rules expert" in his [reddit AMA](http://www.reddit.com/r/rpg/comments/2l69tp/ama_mike_mearls_codesigner_of_dd_5_head_of_dd_rd/cls0mfe). Great research on the answer!

Comment: We don't generally signal our edits in the answers, so I removed your two updates. Love how thorough this answer is. :)

Comment: Yeah, interestingly the blurb on locks and manacles you posted state you need proficiency but don’t say you need the tools...

Comment: Jeremy Crawford clarified the specific "lock" mentioned in PHB p.152 in this tweet here: https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/700131015449128960. This confirms that tool proficiency is not required to use a tool, unless the item specifically mentions it.

Comment: And here is an OFFICIAL answer from Jeremy Crafword in a tweet where I asked him directly: he confirms that proficiency isn't required to use a tool.
https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/1073653310681362432

Comment: @ActiveNick: [Crawford's tweets are no longer official rulings as of a month after your comment](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/140221/33569), but it's still potentially a useful reference.

Comment: Could it be that the answer to whether you need proficiency to attempt to use thieves' tools depends on the specific task? It sounds like most references to picking a lock tend to imply you need proficiency, whereas disarming traps can be done without proficiency.

Answer (score 21):

You must both possess and be proficient with thieves' tools in order to use them to pick a lock:

> a creature proficient with thieves’ tools can pick
> this lock with a successful DC 15 Dexterity check. ([Player's D&D Basic Rules page 49](https://web.archive.org/web/20220228192604/https://dnd.wizards.com/articles/features/basicrules)).

To answer both questions:

- A. Yes you need a thieves' tools to pick a lock
- B. Yes, you need to be proficient with them in order to do so.

The "pick a lock" part of the Dex check seems to indicate that *to use the tool* is a Dex check, and then you'd need proficiency (per the definition of lock), and thus picking a lock is a Dex check plus your thieves' tool proficiency bonus.

So, ultimately, the conclusion is that you need the tools (though in a pinch you might not have them and could improvise, so good call on disadvantage).

It's worth noting that Mike Mearls, designer of D&D indicates that tools aren't required and neither is proficiency. It's worth noting that this is in contrast to the text (in the case of locks/manacles), so this may be cleaned up in teh DMG:

> anyone can use tools, prof bonus adds if proficient. No tools, DM can say no check or disadvantage. [Mearls](https://twitter.com/mikemearls/status/533109977141874688)

Comment: Though [Jeremy Crawford's tweets are no longer official rulings](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/140221/33569), Crawford clarified in a [February 2016 tweet](https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/700131015449128960) that the first quote is a rule specifically for the "lock" item listed under adventuring gear, not a rule for all locks or for thieves' tools in general. He reiterated this in a [December 2018 tweet](https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/1073653310681362432) as well.

Comment: This should be the right answer. WotC has several erratas published and they had the opportunity of clarifying the PHB or the DMG about this specific topic. They didn't, so we should follow the rules I'm the books. A bunch of tweets are not the solution.

Answer (score 2):

#### Not in all cases

In the WoTC published *Out of the Abyss* campaign, there is a lock where the in game description says:

> A character using thieves' tools can pick the lock with a successful DC 20 dexterity check. A character using makeshift tools can attempt the same check but has disadvantage.

I think it's clear: some locks can be picked without thieves' tools.

The full excerpt (contains Out of the Abyss spoilers):

> **11. Slave Pen**
>
>  This cave is built to hold captives until they are sent to Menzoberranzan to be sold as slaves.
>  The gate to the slave pen is kept locked. **A character using thieves' tools can pick the lock** with a successful DC 20 Dexterity check. **A character using makeshift tools can attempt the same check but has disadvantage.**
>  A lock-picking attemt might draw the attention of the guards, requiring a Dexterity (Stealth) check contested by the guards' passive Wisdom (Perception) score to carry it off without notice. Each of the guards on duty in the other areas of the outpost has a key to the gate hanging from a belt ring. Breaking the gate's lock and forcing it open requires a successful DC 20 Strength check.
>  <sub>(emphasis added)</sub>

Answer (score 1):

### No

What you need are lock picks. Thieves tools contain lock picks.

### Answers saying otherwise fall for a logical fallacy

"Locks can be picked using thieves tools. Therefore, you need thieves tools to pick locks."

Think of it another way;

"Spaghetti can be eaten with chopsticks. Therefore, you need chopsticks to eat spaghetti."

I can eat spaghetti perfectly well with a fork. Or my bare fingers. Or lock picks.

I can also go to the shop and buy a fork. Or a full set of cutlery including forks.

Comment: “What you need are lock picks” do you have a citation for this assertion?

Comment: I believe what Thomas Markov means is that in the real world, lock picks are one item among many in a set of Thieves' Tools, but the game does not distinguish them as a separate item - unless you have a citation that they are?

Comment: Actually, you would need a citation that one can only purchase lock picks if they purchase a set of thieves tools.

Comment: As a note, [*Xanathar's Guide to Everything*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/xgte/dungeon-masters-tools#ThievesTools) does specify that thieves' tools include a set of lock picks (among other things). I don't think Thomas is saying that you can only purchase lockpicks if you purchase thieves' tools; he's just saying that the game generally just mentions "thieves' tools" when talking about needing to pick a lock, rather than referring to "lockpicks" specifically.