# What options exist for player-controlled traps?

Tags: dnd-5e, character-creation, traps, dnd-adventurers-league

I have a player looking to design a character whose previous profession of trapping heavily influences their adventuring style. **What features, items, spells, or other player resources would allow them to set 'hasty' style traps in no more than a couple of minutes (such as the hunting trap item, or Cordon of Arrows spell).**

By 'traps' I mean methods or mechanisms designed to influence, hinder, or expose enemies, which must be set up before use, operate on a trigger (set off by target or by trapper are both fine), and in which the trapper is not the immediate source of the effect (so just readying a fireball while hiding would not count).

Besides the hunting trap and Cordon of Arrows, options seem to be limited, I expect in an effort to preserve action economy as much as possible.

This game in question is part of adventurers league, so I would prefer options using AL legal resources rather than other ones or GM improv.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The 7th-level *Symbol* spell allows you to set a trap with a variety of different effects and a customised trigger. It takes a minute to cast, but this is still within the bounds you set.

The 3rd-level spell *Glyph of Warding* is similar, but takes an hour to cast, so it doesn't quite suit your needs. Note that it's by far the most flexible option if you can manage the casting time, since you can store an enormous variety of other spells in it.

The 6th-level spell *Guards and Wards* has, among its various effects, the ability to cast *Suggestion* on any creature who passes through a specific square. It's a pretty unreliable trap, and the 10-minute casting time isn't ideal either, but I figured it was worth a mention.

If you're lucky enough to find one, the Mirror of Life Trapping from the DMG is a slightly niche, but very powerful trap.

The infamous Sphere of Annihilation is worth mentioning, but only as a "trap" that fulfills *none* of your requirements.

Comment: The 1st level spell 'Alarm' also functions in exposing enemies: https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/alarm